# Rotate Feature or Geometry OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, coordinate-system

I would like to programmatically rotate a feature (or its associated geometry) in OpenLayers3. I know I can rotate the view, but I'd like to apply the rotation to the feature/geometry only.

Comment: You can use the geometry object's [rotate](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Geometry.html#rotate) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate an icon using the style. See the [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html?unstable=true) for an icon style. There may be some other styles that also rotate, I'm not sure. This is the only one I've used.